# Filter through two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays and I want to filter through one array with a values of another array. Thus, I have cars array and I want to filter through cars with values of filter array. My code is as follows :

```
let cars = [
  {name: "Audi", price: "1000", transmission: "Manual"},
  {name: "Golf", price: "2000", transmission: "Manual"},
  {name: "Passat", price: "3000", transmission: "Automatic"},
  {name: "Seat", price: "4000", transmission: "Manual"}
];

let filters = [
  {searchFilter : ["price", 2000, 3000]},
  {searchFilter : ["transmission", "", "automatic"]},
];

let carsToShow = "";

let result = cars.filter ( c => {
  let carsToShow = "";
  return filters.filter( f => {
    if(f.searchFilter[0] === "price"){
      carsToShow = c.price >= f.searchFilter[1] && c.price <= f.searchFilter[2]
    }

    if(f.searchFilter[0] === "transmission"){
      if(f.searchFilter[1] !== ""){
        carsToShow = c.transmission.toLowerCase() === "manual"
      } 

      if(f.searchFilter[2] !== ""){
        carsToShow = c.transmission.toLowerCase() === "automatic"
      } 
    }

    return carsToShow;
  })

})

console.log(result);
```

In this case the result should be `{name: "Passat", price: "3000", transmission: "Automatic"}`. But it doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: *"My code is something like this"* "Something like"? Then what is it *really*?

Comment: How are the filters meant to be applied? Is there significance to where they are in the array? E.g., the fact that `3000` and `automatic` are both at index 2? Or is it just "entries that match both filters"? And what's the significance of the `""` transmission filter?

Comment: No, there is no significance where they are in the array? If there is a smarter way to create the filters array, say it. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I'd do is structure the entries in the `filters` so the `[0]` entry of the array isn't special:

```
let filters = [
  {filter: "price", values: [2000, 3000]},
  {filter: "transmission", values: ["", "automatic"]},
];
```

Ideally, the data would be consistent in terms of using numbers or strings for `price` rather than using numbers in one place and strings in another, but I'm going to assume that's a design constraint.

Then it's a matter of weeding out the entries where any filter doesn't match: So for each car, we use `filters.some` to find a filter entry that doesn't match:

```
let result = cars.filter(c => !filters.some(f => {
  let value = c[f.filter].toLowerCase();
  return f.values.findIndex(v => v == value) == -1;
}));
```

Live Copy:

```js
let cars = [
    { name: "Audi",  price: "1000", transmission: "Manual" },
    { name: "Golf", price: "2000", transmission: "Manual" },
    { name: "Passat", price: "3000", transmission: "Automatic" },
    { name: "Seat", price: "4000", transmission: "Manual" }
];

let filters = [
  {filter: "price", values: [2000, 3000]},
  {filter: "transmission", values: ["", "automatic"]},
];

//let carsToShow = "";     <== This wasn't used for anything

let result = cars.filter(c => !filters.some(f => {
  let value = c[f.filter].toLowerCase();
  return f.values.findIndex(v => v == value) == -1;
}));

console.log(result);
```

Note I'm using loose equality in the `findIndex` call (which is why it's not just `indexOf`), so that `2000 == "2000"`. But again, ideally the data and the filter would have the same type so we could use

```
return f.values.inexOf(value) == -1;
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for all explanations.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), for every search condition.

```js
var cars = [{ name: "Audi", price: "1000", transmission: "Manual" }, { name: "Golf", price: "2000", transmission: "Manual" }, { name: "Passat", price: "3000", transmission: "Automatic" }, { name: "Seat", price: "4000", transmission: "Manual" }],
    filters = [{ searchFilter: ["price", 2000, 3000] }, { searchFilter: ["transmission", "", "automatic"] }],
    result = cars.filter(c =>
        filters.every(f => {
            if (f.searchFilter[0] === "price") {
                return c.price >= f.searchFilter[1] && c.price <= f.searchFilter[2]
            }
            if (f.searchFilter[0] === "transmission") {
                return c.transmission.toLowerCase() === f.searchFilter[1] || c.transmission.toLowerCase() === f.searchFilter[2];
            }
        }
    ));
    
console.log(result);
```

A suggestion for using a more concise data structure for searching with an object, like

> ```
> { 
>     /* color: 'red', */                                // a single value
>     price: {                                           // a range/interval
>         min: 2000, 
>         max: 3000
>     },
>     transmission: v => v.toLowerCase() === 'automatic' // a function
> }
> ```

```js
var useConditions = search => a => Object.keys(search).every(k => 
        a[k] === search[k] ||
        typeof search[k] === 'object' && +search[k].min <= a[k] &&  a[k] <= +search[k].max ||
        typeof search[k] === 'function' && search[k](a[k])
    ),
    cars = [{ name: "Audi", price: "1000", transmission: "Manual" }, { name: "Golf", price: "2000", transmission: "Manual" }, { name: "Passat", price: "3000", transmission: "Automatic" }, { name: "Seat", price: "4000", transmission: "Manual" }],
    filters = { price: { min: 2000, max: 3000 }, transmission: v => v.toLowerCase() === 'automatic' };

console.log(cars.filter(useConditions(filters)));
```

Answer (score 0):

but if you need get more datas than one...

```
<script>
"use strict"
let cars = [
  {name: "Audi", price: "1000", transmission: "Manual"},
  {name: "Golf", price: "2000", transmission: "Manual"},
  {name: "Passat", price: "3000", transmission: "Automatic"},
  {name: "Passat", price: "2500", transmission: "Automatic"},
  {name: "Seat", price: "4000", transmission: "Manual"}
];

let filters = [
  {searchFilter : ["price", 2000, 3000]},
  {searchFilter : ["transmission", "", "automatic"]},
];



let result = cars.filter ( c => {
  let carsToShow=false;
  let carsToShowtran = false;
  let carsToShowPrice = false;
 let re= filters.filter( f => { 
    if(f.searchFilter[0] === "price"){
      carsToShowPrice = c.price >= f.searchFilter[1] && c.price <= f.searchFilter[2]      
    }
    if(f.searchFilter[0] === "transmission"){
      if(f.searchFilter[1] !== ""){
        carsToShowtran = c.transmission.toLowerCase() === "manual"
      } 
      if(f.searchFilter[2] !== ""){
        carsToShowtran = c.transmission.toLowerCase() === "automatic"
      } 
    }
    if(carsToShowtran && carsToShowPrice){
        carsToShow=true;
    }   
    return carsToShow;
  })
  if(re.length!=0){
    return true;
  }

})

console.log(result);
</script>
```